# How can I uninstall Microsoft Word Online on Manjaro (Gnome ver.)?

Tags: manjaro, uninstall

Manjaro with Gnome comes with some preloaded applications. One of them is a suite of Microsoft Word Online applications (Word, Outlook, etc). And I would like to uninstall them, since I'll be using either Libre Office or Google Docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those Microsoft applications can be found as the package "ms-office-online". One can simply open the default package manager, search for this name, and untick the box to remove it.

Comment: I may want to add that these applications are actually *NOT* really installed at all on your system. It's only a very simple wrapper script(s) that open those web-application in a web-browser. Thus is just a website you are looking at (hence the name Micro$oft Office Online).